# Use write() system call to send a UDP broadcast

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, broadcast

I am doing some programming on Linux platform.

I want to make a UDP broadcast.

I set the socket option `SO_BROADCAST`, when I invoke the `sendto()` system call it perfectly sends the broadcast, but when I use `bind()` to bind the socket descriptor with the destination address and invoke the `write()` system call, it raises an error message:

```
Destination address required
```

Please give me some tips, thanks!

Comment: `bind()` is used to set the source, that is to bind to the local interface you want to have your data send out through. `bind()` is not used to define the target address.

Comment: And in any case what's the problem with using `sendto()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bind() doesn't set up the destination address, it sets up the local (source) address.

You need to use connect() to establish the destination address.

UDP is ofcourse connectionless, but calling connect() will allow you to associate the socket with a remote address - this allows you to use write() and send() on the socket. However, the socket will then only accept incoming messages coming from the address you specify in connect() as well - which might not be desired for broadcast traffic since there should never be messages coming *from* the broadcast address.